# Unding in one step

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is there a way to make VBA code of a Word 2013 macro execute as block, so if I undo it, it doesn’t undo the macro by the individual steps it goes through to execute? I would like macros to act more like built in functions.

I have macro that moves the cursor to the end of a word then deletes the previous three letters. If I undo it, I see each of the three letters reappear one by one.

I may not have worded this right. I was wondering if there was code to wrap a macro in to get Word to treat a macro like a built in Work command that executes all a once rather than executing a series of recorded steps. Then if I run a macro and decide I don't like the results, I can click on undo and the entire macro rewinds and undoes.

Comment: Please post relevant codes.

Comment: The `Application.Undo` undoes action by action what was done. If you want the three letters to reappear again on undo, then you need to delete them all together with the macro.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `Application.UndoRecord` as follows:

**Method One:**

```
Sub YourMacroName
    Dim objUndo As UndoRecord 
    'Declares the variable objUndo of the UndoRecord type
    Set objUndo = Application.UndoRecord 
    'sets the object to an actual item on the undo stack
    objUndo.StartCustomRecord ("Undo Stack Display Text")
    'Tells Word where to begin "recording" the undo record
    'This item also lets you set the text you want to appear in the undo drop-down in word.

        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord 
        'Moves to the end of the current word
        Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=3, Extend:=True 
        'Selects the last three letters of the word
        Selection.Delete
        'Deletes the last three letters of the word
    objUndo.EndCustomRecord
    'Denotes the End of The Undo Record
End Sub
```

You may also want to look at Microsoft's article on using the [Application.UndoRecord Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh420330.aspx).

Alternatively, as @Matteo NNZ Mentioned, you can just delete the three characters at once. To do that, use the code below.

**Method Two:**

```
Sub YourMacroName
     Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord 
    'Moves to the end of the current word
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=3, Extend:=True 
    'Selects the last three letters of the word
    Selection.Delete
    'Deletes the last three letters of the word
End Sub
```

The downside to the second method is that you can't control the Name of the Item in the undo drop-down.

Both methods are limited in that they do not restore the cursor to its original position.

Comment: The first method is the winner, since it generalizes.  As a note, I use the macro name as the name of the custom undo record, for example  objUndo.StartCustomRecord ("Your Macro Name")

Answer (score 1):

Thanks JRP that a big help, to solve this issue:

> Both methods are limited in that they do not restore the cursor to its original position.

Once the `UndoRecord` is recording, add a space at the end of the current selection `Selection.InsertAfter (" ")` and remove it again.

The approximate block I use is:

```
Dim originalSelection As Range

Application.UndoRecord.StartCustomRecord ("Delete previous")

Set originalSelection = Selection.Range
Selection.InsertAfter (" ")
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.TypeBackspace
originalSelection.Select

... your code here ...

Application.UndoRecord.EndCustomRecord
```